# Workflow 4 InArgument<List<int>>

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

In Workflow 3.x you can have a dependency property List<int> and in the designer you could click on the "..." and add values directly to the list<int>

In workflow 4, how is this achieved? Is the only way is to define a Variable type [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and then using the [`AddToCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd648043.aspx) activity to add values to the list. And then pass the variable as the InArgument of the custom activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a collection literal in VB (or C#), but you can create an expression that creates a collection initialisation expression.

In VB:

```
New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

is equivalent to the C#:

```
new List<T> { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

and this can be used in the expression for an [`Assign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.assign.aspx) activity or in the default for a variable.

Another alternative is to create a custom activity derived from either [`CodeActivity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.codeactivity.aspx) (if no result) or [`CodeActivity<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465967.aspx) (if there is a result). This could be combined with a custom designer if needed.